# Python (for Ren'Py Engine) ui.input into button?

Tags: python, renpy

I designed a character creation page, and included a bit where a person can input their name with ui.input() but the problem is, they can't push any buttons or do anything at all without submitting the text first and I am trying to figure out how to turn this ui.input into a clickable so it is only active when its selected.

Then engine has a page on the ui.input (and includes explaining that the button arg is possible) but it doesn't really give me any other example other than button=None. and anything else I try, the game won't even load.

Sorry if this is a  really noob question. Seems like the most simple thing.

This is what I have for that part if it helps..

```
 ui.input('', xalign=0.5, yalign=0.5)
 first_name = ui.interact()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a character creation **screen** and using a **graphic button**?

In a custom screen, you can control everything using buttons and code, which is, in some senses, outside of your story.